# C++ class to read and write opendocument spreadheets (*.ods)

Tags: c++, qt, ods, opendocument

I was looking for a Qt implementation (since Qt already support export of rich text to odt) but found none of them.
Then I was astonished that I can't find any C++ class to read/write ods files.

I need to import/export tables with basic formating and was thinking that using a open source format would be a good idea. But it looks like it is mission impossible in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Qt5 library for working with .ods, check it out:
https://github.com/f35f22fan/QOds

Comment: Nice, any chance it will work with Qt4 before I give it a try?

Comment: Tl;dr: unlikely.
When I moved to Qt I went straight to Qt5. So I'd have to learn
Qt4 first before doing the port and I have no incentive since
as I said I'm not working with Qt4. So unless someone else
does the port to Qt4 and submits the patches..

Answer (score 1):

The [Calligra](http://www.calligra.org/) framework will let you do this just fine, and since you're looking for a Qt based thing, then that would probably be your best option :) Further information on using Calligra for development can be found here: http://community.kde.org/Calligra

Answer (score -1):

Not exactily what you wanted but check this out:

[OpenOffice API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/cpp/ref/names/index.html)